# How do you step through $http response code blocks in the browser?

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, firefox, angularjs

I am trying to step through some code to figure out an odd behavior in my app.

When I get to an $http.post function call, I am only able to step through the function call, the .success function call, and the .error function call.

I am never able to wait for the response and step through the appropriate code block.

```
$http.post("php/someFunction.php")
  .success(function(data, status)
  {
    ... do thing ONE;
  })
  .error(function(data, status)
  {
    ... do thing TWO;
  });
```

In this example, I can never step through either thing ONE or thing TWO.

Are there any debug tips or tools I can use to actually perform the ajax call, wait for the actual response, and step through the appropriate code block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `debugger` statement:

```
$http.post("php/someFunction.php")
  .success(function(data, status)
  {
    debugger; // debugger will kick in if success
    ... do thing ONE;
  })
  .error(function(data, status)
  {
    debugger; // debugger will kick in if error
    ... do thing TWO;
  });
```